# getting only public posts from /feed using an app or page_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display the facebook wall (exactly as it is on FB) of my companys fb-page on our homepage. So Iam quering //feed

When I use an access_token which is associated with the Graph API Explorer Application (top left in Api Explorer) everything is fine and Iam getting only the public post that are visible on my FB-page (This is exactly what I want).
But when I change the access_token to an app_token or a page_token I also get "status" posts in the result (like " likes a link."). I DONT want these status messages on our homepage.

What can I do to get the first result with a never expiring access_token (like app or page_token).
Filtering the result afer is not an option as it messes up pagination.

Thanks for any help with this. It's driving me crazy since weeks :-(

Comment: Have you tried `/{page-id}/posts` instead of feed?

Comment: /{page-id}/posts returns exactly the same results as /{page-id}/feed